# django voting app - relationship between different models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple voting app which has 2 models Poll and Choice as most voting apps do.

Poll model has the following fields:

1. question - charField
2. pub_date - date and time
3. end_date - date and time

Also, each Poll has 2 choices.

Choice model has the following fields:

1. Poll - ForeignKey
2. choice - ImageField
3. vote - Integer

I have another model Person. A Poll occurs between 2 people from the Person model.

Person Model:

1. Name - Charfield
2. age - charfield
3. image - imagefield
   ...

I want to accomplish the following in the admin;

1. Create Poll (this is a simple one)
2. Create Choice - take image from Person Model rather than uploading new.
3. if a choice is added against a poll, the choice and the votes on that choice automatically show up as read only fields on Poll.
4. Person model shows how many Polls has the Person taken part in and how many of them has he won and lost.

Points 2,3 and 4 are the ones I am struggling with. please keep your responses simple, I am a newbie.

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

class Choice(models.Model):
    Poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.ImageField(upload_to="choice")
    vote = models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
```

let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: please, paste your models code and what did you try ?

Comment: @levi Hey, I just added the models and also formatted the text above. It wasn't displaying as I intended initially.

Comment: @levi I had previously tried using foreignKey in both Poll and Choice model, cross referencing each other but this did not work since lot of work goes into it. create poll, then create choices and then go back to poll and select choices (each poll has only 2 choices so I added 2 foreign fields).

Answer (score 0):

It is not totally clear to me what you want to achieve. Implying you want to answer the question in reference to two images I would use the following models:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    person1 = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name ="+") #"+" to block reverse reference
    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Person,related_name ="+")
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()    

class Choice(models.Model):
    Poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    vote = models.IntegerField()

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
def votes_sum(self):
        return len( self.choice_set.all()) #this returns all votes
```

In the admin you can then add the Choice model as Inline to the Poll.

```
class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra=1

class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

class VotesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 'votes_sum']
    readonly_fields = ('votes_sum',)
```

I did not test this code but you should get an idea how you can do this.